# Fluid Simulation, make the fluid to be absorbed

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a fluid falling on top of a plane.

I want the fluid (water) to be absorbed by the plane, like a cloth would do.

How can i do that?
[image]

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how you want the absorption to be visualized? Like do you want the fluid to still be visual in some way after the absorption? Do you want the fluid to stick to the plane in a sort of way? How do you want the fluid to have an effect on the plane? (example: plane get's thicker on fluid interaction). What is your main goal? A Bounty towels commercial or a scientific visualization of fluid absorption? Should someone recommend force fields, a fluid outflow or a combination of fluid and dynamic paint???

Comment: My final goal is for a commercial, the plane (cloth) gets wet and it dries fast (and i will use the wet maps/dynamic paint for that). I just need the fluid to get absorbed,  it would be cool if the plane get's thicker on the interaction i guess, thank you again.

Comment: Why not have an outflow object aligned with the top of your plane? It may make the fluid disappear quite rapidly, but maybe fiddle with the simulation speed if need be.

Comment: if i put an outflow the fluid simulation doesn't work, i mean that the fluid disappear as soon as it touches the plane

Comment: I was trying to set up a scene where the fluid interacts with the plane with dynamic paint (like you have already done). And then make the dynamic paint interact with a solidify modifier (to make it thicker on interaction) by assigning the solidify to the dynamic paint vertex group directly. But that doesn't work... So I removed the solidify, changed the "surface type" of the dynamic paint canvas to "displace" (make sure the canvas has enough subdivisions); and I got a sort of absorption on interaction effect. I'm still trying to finetune things, but it might be a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the Dynamic Paint Canvas type to "Displacement" and setting the "Displace Factor" to negative 1 (-1) gives this effect.

[image]

(*make sure the plane/canvas has enough subdivisions)

Comment: Also tried it in 2.8, but dynamic paint doesn't seem to work yet (Not like 2.79 works "out of the box"). Or I might be missing something, like a new added step for 2.8.

Comment: In 2.8 there are occurrences where you cannot see the result right away, but if you bake it, it works (like weight paint). Not sure why, not convenient, but it works (afaik).

Comment: @ Kiskit. Aha! Tnx for answering.